# Debugging tool to compare parameters for MSVS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-debugging

Are there any plugins for MSVS (any version) to compare function parameters?

So - I have to call a function with a lots of parameters, which are non-POD types, can be polymorphic objects... anyway, legacy spaghetti code. Refactoring is out of the question.

Sometimes the function outputs correctly, sometimes it doesn't. I want to compare the parameters between calls which yield correct results and the others. I could debug this, and I could compare parameters by hand, but this isn't the first time I've encountered this issue and I'm thinking it would be a lot easier if we had something like Araxis Merge (possibly in the form of a macro) that would let you compare parameters between calls. Know of any such tools?

Comment: Why cannot you check parameneters during several runs of program without debugging? And how you determine whether function was successfull or not?

Comment: @Mikhail 1) how would you do that? 2) Regression testing.

Comment: Seems like I don't really understand your workflow. Can you add some logging or parameter checking in your tests? Or in this function? You also can use Watch window to check if some variables changed - they will turn red.

Comment: @Mikhail I can't change the code, and even if I could, I'd have to add it in ~100 classes. I can add it in the function, but don't see how that would help. I can use the Watch window, but variables change between calls to the function, and since there's so many of them and they are quite large, it would take a lot of time.